# How many times the Super Bowl teams have both lost to a common opponent during the regular season?

Tags: trivia, american-football, nfl, super-bowl

The Cincinnati Bengals and Los Angeles Rams will be playing in Super Bowl 55. Both of these teams played the Green Bay packers in the regular season. The Packers Beat the Bengals in Week 5, and beat the Rams in week 12.

How many times in Super Bowl era, have the 2 teams playing in the Super Bowl had a common team in their regular season schedule who they lost to?

Comment: [The long-established community consensus is that trivia questions are on-topic](https://sports.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23/should-we-allow-sports-trivia); if you wish to reopen that debate, you are welcome to start a _polite_ discussion on [Meta](https://sports.meta.stackexchange.com/) but please [use language which will build a community that is rooted in kindness, collaboration, and mutual respect](https://sports.stackexchange.com/conduct).